# Generate symbols for debugging in wndbg

Tags: c++, windbg, symbols

I have an C++ MFC project I'd like to debug with wndbg, and I need to generate the symbols for it when compiling the project.

Does anybody know how to do that?

I thought that de .pdb files where enough, but wndbg complains it cannot find symbol files at the path where these .pdb file reside for my project.

Answer (score 1):

There are several paths, which windbg uses to find the pdb's.

1. An absolute path to your pdb is stored in your exe/dll/lib files. If you debug the app on your computer, where you build it, it 'magically' finds the pdb if it wasn'T deleted prematurely.
2. You can add the pdb to the search path. Either in the Menu -> File -> Symbol Path or on the command line with `.sympath+ <path>` command.
3. You can add your pdbs after build to a local symbol-server.

Comment: I tried your second point, and it says it cannot find the symbols...

C:\mysymbols\ is what I put in the SymbolPath dialog, there I put the pdb files that were created when it compiled.  The debugger is on a different machine to the one I built the project on.